# Pentaho bi server 4.0.0 GA stopped working after an unexpected shutdown

Tags: pentaho, java-6

There is an issue with our Pentaho setup. This issue happened again several months ago. Suddenly, everything went back to normal after restarting the server and updating the Java environment variable. But again we encountered the same problem. I tried wiping all the cash files from our Pentaho setup and re-installing everything, but I kept receiving the following errors while downloading it.

Pentaho 4.0.0 GA is now being run with (Java 1.6.0_24) - OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (rhel-1.45.1.11.1.el6-x86_64).

The following directories and configuration files have been wiped:

[Reset the pentaho cash menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfrSC.png)

```
pentaho-solutions/system/.orient/
tomcat/{work,temp}
~/.pentaho/
```

Logs when Pentaho starts:

```
17:03:45,462 ERROR [Logger] misc-class org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager: PluginManager.ERROR_0011 - Failed to register plugin cdc
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PlatformPluginRegistrationException: PluginManager.ERROR_0017 - Could not load lifecycle listener [pt.webdetails.cdc.CdcLifeCycleListener] for plugin cdc
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.bootStrapPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:163)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.registerPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:197)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:340)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:322)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:289)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mondrian/spi/SegmentCache
    at pt.webdetails.cdc.CdcLifeCycleListener.<clinit>(CdcLifeCycleListener.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.bootStrapPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:160)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mondrian.spi.SegmentCache
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 40 more
17:03:45,469 ERROR [Logger] Error end:
17:03:45,486 WARN  [ServletAdapterContentGenerator] $HOME/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/saiku-adhoc
-- listing properties --
saiku-adhoc.metadata.file=c:/TargetPlatforms/saiku-server/tomca...
saiku-adhoc.default.template=saiku_small
saiku-adhoc.default.template=saiku_small

2021-06-12 17:03:45:819 INFO Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.saiku.adhoc.rest [PackagesResourceConfig]
2021-06-12 17:03:45:864 INFO Root resource classes found:
  class org.saiku.adhoc.rest.PentahoRepositoryResource
  class org.saiku.adhoc.rest.ExportResource
  class org.saiku.adhoc.rest.StandaloneCdaResource
  class org.saiku.adhoc.rest.QueryResource
  class org.saiku.adhoc.rest.MetadataDiscoverResource [ScanningResourceConfig]
2021-06-12 17:03:45:864 INFO No provider classes found. [ScanningResourceConfi
```

When downloading the report, the following logs appear:

```
17:52:57,655 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Deprecated behavior: None of the data-factories was able to handle the query 'sql'. Returning empty tablemodel instead of failing hard.
17:52:57,655 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Be aware that the default for this setting will change in version 0.8.11. To avoid this warning, make sure that all data-sources are properly configured and that no report references illegal queries.
17:52:57,655 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Be aware that the default for this setting will change in version 0.8.11. To avoid this warning, make sure that all data-sources are properly configured and that no report references illegal queries.
17:52:57,726 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Deprecated behavior: None of the data-factories was able to handle the query 'sql'. Returning empty tablemodel instead of failing hard.
17:52:57,726 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Be aware that the default for this setting will change in version 0.8.11. To avoid this warning, make sure that all data-sources are properly configured and that no report references illegal queries.
17:52:57,726 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Be aware that the default for this setting will change in version 0.8.11. To avoid this warning, make sure that all data-sources are properly configured and that no report references illegal queries.
17:52:57,737 ERROR [SimpleReportingComponent] [execute] Component execution failed.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.fonts.awt.AWTFontMetrics
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.fonts.awt.AWTFontMetricsFactory.createMetrics(AWTFontMetricsFactory.java:62)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.fonts.registry.DefaultFontStorage.getFontMetrics(DefaultFontStorage.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.getFontMetrics(AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.java:708)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.getFontMetrics(AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.java:820)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.getBaselineInfo(AbstractOutputProcessorMetaData.java:731)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.updateStaticProperties(ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.java:224)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.startBlockLevelBox(ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.java:253)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.processBlockLevelChild(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:177)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.IterateVisualProcessStep.startProcessing(IterateVisualProcessStep.java:44)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.process.ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.compute(ComputeStaticPropertiesProcessStep.java:107)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.AbstractRenderer.validatePages(AbstractRenderer.java:895)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processPaginationLevel(AbstractReportProcessor.java:822)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:533)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processReport(AbstractReportProcessor.java:1522)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.output.XLSOutput.generate(XLSOutput.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.SimpleReportingComponent.execute(SimpleReportingComponent.java:1079)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.ExecuteReportContentHandler.doExport(ExecuteReportContentHandler.java:229)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.ExecuteReportContentHandler.createReportContent(ExecuteReportContentHandler.java:67)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.platform.plugin.ReportContentGenerator.createContent(ReportContentGenerator.java:66)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SimpleContentGenerator.createContent(SimpleContentGenerator.java:66)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GenericServlet.doGet(GenericServlet.java:261)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
17:52:57,758 ERROR [SolutionEngine] 4d91c350-cb81-11eb-9784-47a4e37b752c:SOLUTION-ENGINE:session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
17:52:57,933 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Deprecated behavior: None of the data-factories was able to handle the query 'sql'. Returning empty tablemodel instead of failing hard.
17:52:57,934 WARN  [CascadingDataFactory] Be aware that the default for this setting will change in version 0.8.11. To avoid this warning, make sure that all data-sources are properly configured and that no report references illegal queries.
```

[Pentaho startup dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pFXR.png)

[whereis java result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGSX2.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Pentaho documentation ([Systems without video cards](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0F0/0L0/020#Systems%20without%20video%20cards)), there is a reference to headless servers, and I have added the following option to the "CATALINA_OPTS" section of the "start-pentaho.sh" script.

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

[also checked this forum](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/143291-kitchen-sh-X11-issue-when-using-reporting-engine/)

[image]